# How do I set defaultSearchHandlingStrict via the Google Healthcare API?

Tags: google-healthcare-api

I'm able to fetch a fhirStore object with the JS api, but I don't see any decent examples of how to update the fhirStore to use defaultSearchHandlingStrict = true.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Cloud Healthcare API docs have a guide for how to update a FHIR store config, [link](https://cloud.google.com/healthcare-api/docs/how-tos/fhir#editing_a_fhir_store). Updating the strict handling behaviour can be done in the same way as other properties of the FHIR store config. If you're using JS this might look something like

```
const updateStrictHandling = async () => {
  // TODO(developer): uncomment these lines before running the sample
  // const cloudRegion = 'us-central1';
  // const projectId = 'adjective-noun-123';
  // const datasetId = 'my-dataset';
  // const fhirStoreId = 'my-fhir-store';
  const name = `projects/${projectId}/locations/${cloudRegion}/datasets/${datasetId}/fhirStores/${fhirStoreId}`;
  const request = {
    name,
    updateMask: 'defaultSearchHandlingStrict',
    resource: {
      defaultSearchHandlingStrict: true,
    },
  };

  return healthcare.projects.locations.datasets.fhirStores.patch(request);
};

await updateStrictHandling();
```

(example adapted from the linked page)

Comment: That's just labels and pubsub topics, from what I can see. @Nik Klassen

Comment: Can you try the code and post an error here if you get one?